# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NA'

Tags: python

Estoy realizando un sistema de recomendación pero presenta este error, cuando realizo el siguiente código:

```
N_filas = 100000 # Limitamos el dataset a N_filas
df3rg = Dataset.load_from_df(df2rg[['user_id','id','metascore']][:N_filas],reader)
```

Esto me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
   ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NA'
```

- ¿Qué significa este error?
- ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### ¿Qué significa este error?

Ese error significa que, en tu conversión de cadena a número en coma flotante, esta recibiendo una cadena 'NA', la cual no corresponde a ningún valor numérico válido.

#### ¿Cómo solucionar este problema?

Si quieres obviar las filas que posean el valor *'NA'*, tienes varias opciones como la que ya se ha propuesto. No obstante, yo recomiendo otro enfoque, que consiste en eliminar las filas que contengan el valor *'NA'*. Asumiendo que dicho valor se encuentra en la columna *'metascore'* y que df2rg es un Pandas.DataFrame, el código para hacerlo es:

```
N_filas = 100000 # Limitamos el dataset a N_filas
aux_df = df2rg.drop(df2rg[df2rg['metascore']].index)
df3rg = Dataset.load_from_df(aux_df[['user_id', 'id', 'metascore']][:N_filas], reader)
```

Puedes encontrar más información sobre la función DataFrame.drop en la [documentación oficial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante aclaratorio. No puede convertir la cadena "NA" en un flotante y con razón.

Lo más probable es que de toda tu tabla algunos registros no contengan un numero flotante sino "NA" que vendrá a significar "Not Available".

Donde sea que haces la conversión podrías poner un condicional

```
if tuvariable in 'NA': break
```

y saltarse ese ciclo, un `try/catch` por `ValueError` o comprobar de alguna manera que o bien la variable no contenga 'NA' ni ningún otro texto antes de pasar la conversión o que el resultado de la operación sea un flotante. Hay varias formas de solucionar eso y lo dejo en tus manos.

Sin el resto del código no podemos saber de donde viene el problema